# Vars are getting wiped off while using vm connector in mule 4

Tags: mule

mule doc says they have removed transport barrier so there is no need to have session vars in mule 4. when I am using a VM connector to publish and consume using VM **vars** are getting wiped off. I did cross check with mule 3.9 session vars will be persisted after reaching other flow irrespective of configured VM is one-way to req-res.

```
<vm:config name="vm">
    <vm:queues>
        <vm:queue queueName="publish" />
    </vm:queues>
</vm:config>
<flow name="persistentVM">
    <vm:listener queueName="publish" config-ref="vm"
        numberOfConsumers="1">
        <vm:response>
            <vm:content><![CDATA[
        ]]></vm:content>
        </vm:response>
    </vm:listener>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"
        doc:id="1d624aa2-0aa4-4c5d-a258-0a8135a792ff" message="#[vars.test]" />

</flow>
<flow name="publish">
    <http:listener doc:name="Listener"
        doc:id="68f9601d-d31e-4de6-a448-98a43724de42" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config"
        path="/error" />
    <set-variable value="#['My Message']" doc:name="Set Variable"
        doc:id="861cc914-b1ad-4068-8753-a0fd1915bed4" variableName="test" />
    <vm:publish doc:name="Publish" doc:id="153209cb-49f2-4f80-8305-56dcd046aa3c" config-ref="vm" queueName="publish"/>
```

`

Any comments on this is much helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For  Mule 4 session vars are removed and vars will not propagate across transport barriers. If you want the var in the other flow, you will either have to make it part of the payload and publish it using vm:content, persist it using the ObjectStore or use flows and flow-ref instead of the vm connector.